# Navbar and image slider getting merged

Tags: jquery, html, css

When i merge my `Navbar` and the image `slider` than the `navbar` is getting below the image slider. I have used the `cycle` jquery plugin given on [malsup.com](http://malsup.com) website.
I have attached my code on **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d80na0sd/)**

Comment: Did you reproduce the issue in your fiddle? Because I'm seeing the `navbar` above the images.

Comment: ya its because i have not used images in fiddle..they are blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the fiddle Im seeing that the `navbar` is above the image to start with but when you click to view the `navbar` items then the slideshow `<left and right>` controls are on top of the `navbar items`.

The controls of the navbar are now below the navbar (when it's open). They are ontop of the images where you can't see them because they're blending in with the background.

Im not sure if this is what you were trying to fix but I did add `clear: both` to the `.cycle-slideshow` class. *BTW the images aren't showing up in the fiddle*

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/d80na0sd/1/

Comment: how can i send you my html file?